# Display the error_messages under the fields

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm using this package for my form https://github.com/KuwaitNET/djvue but anyway it's like a general question, I've wrote the following method to validate my phone number field

```
    def validate_phone_number(self, value):
    phone_number = to_python(value)
    if phone_number and not phone_number.is_valid():
        self.fields["phone_number"].error_messages.update({"ph":"Wrong"})
        raise ValidationError(_(u'The phone number entered is not valid.'))
    return value
```

and it works just fine because in my Model:

```
def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        serializer = ContactUsSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            ticket_number = serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse({"ticket_number": ticket_number})
        else:
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors)
    ctx = self.get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ctx["serializer"] = ContactUsSerializer()
    request.is_preview = getattr(request, "is_preview", False)
    return TemplateResponse(
        request, self.get_template(request, *args, **kwargs), ctx
    )
```

and actually when I enter an invalid phone number I'm getting a JsonResponse with the error:

```
0: "The phone number entered is not valid."
```

which is great, but how can I display the updated error message below the phone_number field?? it looks like despite the errors are being updated the displaying is not, should I use Vue or something to achieve that? knowing that the package I'm using does so:

```
<span class="help-block text-danger" v-for="error in errors" :key="error">{( error )}</span>
```

but I'm not sure how and where they render the error, so I want maybe a pure Django way to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vuevalidate library of Vuejs for frontend field validations. Light weight with very good documentation as well
https://vuelidate.js.org/